# Rails and MongoDB testing: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, tdd, mongoid

I made a users models and I'm trying to test it.

I'm new to using MongoDB. Previously I have used SQLite.

My test file contains the followng:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
    @user = users(:john)
  end

  test "should be valid" do
    assert @user.valid?
  end

end
```

And the fixture:

```
john:
  email: john@example
  first_name: John
  last_name: Doe
  date_of_birth: Date.new(1980,5,6)
  gender: male
  occupation: business analyst
```

When I run the tests I get the following error:

```
ERROR["test_should_be_valid", UserTest, 0.02658726099616615]
 test_should_be_valid#UserTest (0.03s)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:         ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: DELETE FROM "users"
```

I think the test file is trying to use ActiveRecord when it should be using Mongo. I'm unsure how to fix this. Here is my user.rb model file:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :email, type: String
  field :first_name, type: String
  field :last_name, type: String
  field :date_of_birth, type: Date
  field :gender, type: String
  field :occupation, type: String

  embeds_one :location, class_name: 'Place', as: :locatable

  #backwards-compatible readers
  def name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end

  def age(dob=self.date_of_birth)
    now = Time.now.utc.to_date
    now.year - dob.year - ((now.month > dob.month || (now.month == dob.month && now.day >= dob.day)) ? 0 : 1)
  end

end
```

EDIT:

Added the following to the top of test_helper.rb:

```
require 'mongoid'
Mongoid.load!("./config/mongoid.yml", "test")
```

Still getting the same error.

Comment: You need to change you test case according to mongoDB.

Comment: You mean the line that says "ActiveSupport::TestCase"?